# Compile a table with start and end dates based off of changes and effective dates

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014. I have a table that tracks employees and every time a change is made in the application there is an effective date set and a new row is inserted it looks like this.

```
ID  EmployeeID  Job Title       Effective Date
1   10          Sales Agent     10/1/2016
3   10          Sales Agent     10/5/2016
7   10          Sales Agent 2   10/15/2016
9   10          Sales Agent 3   10/20/2016
15  10          Sales Agent 3   10/16/2016
2   2           BSA III         10/1/2016
4   2           BSA II          10/1/2016
14  2           BSA III         10/1/2016
```

I need to iterate through the table and if there is a change in job title insert a new row with a new start and end date, and if there is not a new title then ignore the change unless it overwrites an effective date in the previous row. The last row of the employee group should set an end date of 1/1/2999. I have SSIS or SQL I can do this in, but I'm just not sure where to start or how to pull this off. After the process is completed the table result should look like the below.

```
EmployeeID  Job Title       Start Date  End Date
10          Sales Agent     10/1/2016   10/14/2016
10          Sales Agent 2   10/15/2016  10/15/2016
10          Sales Agent 3   10/16/2016  1/1/2999
2           BSA III         10/1/2016   1/1/2999
```

Comment: The "Job Title" in last row should be "Sales Agent 3" right?

Comment: @FLICKER Yes it should. Thank you, I've updated the question.

Comment: @Beth No, because Row ID 15 Overwrites Row ID 9 with an earlier effective date.

Comment: Any change the person can go backwards? I mean could they be Sales Agent 2 10/20/2016?

Comment: @HolmesIV Yes that is a possibility. Also they could transfer from Sales Agent 2 to Workforce Agent or any other combination of job titles within the organization.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the answer you need as well as allow for multiple effective time period for the same job.

```
DROP TABLE #EMP
DROP TABLE #EMPFINAL
Create table #EMP (EmployeeID INT,
             JOBTitle VARCHAR(30),
             EffectiveDate Date
            )

Create table #EMPFINAL (EmployeeID INT,
             JOBTitle VARCHAR(30),
             StateDate Date,
             ENDDATE Date
            )

INSERT INTO #EMP
values (10,'Sales Agent', '2016-10-1')
,(10,'Sales Agent', '2016-10-5')
,(10,'Sales Agent 2', '2016-10-15')
,(10,'Sales Agent 3', '2016-10-20')
,(10,'Sales Agent 3', '2016-10-16')


DECLARE @EMPID INT,
        @JOBTITLE VARCHAR(30),
        @EFFECTIVE DATE,
        @MAXEFF DATE,
        @MAXEMPID INT,
        @MAXJOB VARCHAR(30)


DECLARE REV CURSOR FOR
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, JOBTITLE,EFFECTIVEDATE
FROM #EMP
order by effectivedate

OPEN REV

FETCH NEXT FROM REV
INTO @EMPID, @JOBTITLE,@EFFECTIVE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @MAXEFF = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(EndDate),'1900-01-01') FROM #EMPFINAL WHERE EmployeeID = @EMPID)
SET @MAXEMPID = (SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEEID) FROM #EMPFINAL WHERE ENDDATE = @MAXEFF)
SET @MAXJOB = (SELECT MAX(JOBTitle) FROM #EMPFINAL WHERE ENDDATE = @MAXEFF)

IF @MAXEFF = '1900-01-01'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #EMPFINAL
    VALUES(@EMPID,@JOBTITLE,@EFFECTIVE,'2999-01-01')

END

IF @MAXEMPID = @EMPID and @MAXJOB != @JOBTITLE
BEGIN

    UPDATE #EMPFINAL
    SET ENDDATE = DATEADD(dd,-1,@Effective)
    where ENDDATE = '2999-01-01'
    and JOBTitle != @JOBTITLE

    INSERT INTO #EMPFINAL
    VALUES(@EMPID,@JOBTITLE,@EFFECTIVE,'2999-01-01')
END


FETCH NEXT FROM REV
INTO @EMPID, @JOBTITLE,@EFFECTIVE

END

CLOSE REV;
DEALLOCATE REV;

Select * 
From #EMPFINAL
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create test data:**

```
select * into #t
from (
select 
1 ID, 10 EmployeeID, 'Sales Agent' JobTitle, cast('10/1/2016' as date) EffectiveDate
union select 3   ,10 ,'Sales Agent'     ,'10/5/2016'
union select 7   ,10 ,'Sales Agent 2'   ,'10/15/2016'
union select 9   ,10 ,'Sales Agent 3'   ,'10/20/2016'
union select 15  ,10 ,'Sales Agent 3'   ,'10/16/2016'
union select 2   ,2  ,'BSA III'         ,'10/1/2016'
union select 4   ,2  ,'BSA II'          ,'10/1/2016'
union select 14  ,2  ,'BSA III'         ,'10/1/2016'
) a
```

**Code:**

```
;with cc as (
select ID, EmployeeID, JobTitle, EffectiveDate
  , LEAD(JobTitle) over (partition by EmployeeID order by EffectiveDate, ID) NextJobTitle
  , LAG(EffectiveDate) over (partition by EmployeeID, JobTitle order by EffectiveDate, ID) StartDate
  , LEAD(EffectiveDate) over (partition by EmployeeID order by EffectiveDate, ID) EndDate
  from #t
)
, c2 as (
  select ID, EmployeeID
  , JobTitle
  , EffectiveDate
  , NextJobTitle
  , StartDate
  , dateadd(day, -1, EndDate) EndDate
from cc
)
, c3 as (
select 
  EmployeeID, JobTitle
  , IsNull(StartDate, EffectiveDate) as StartDate
  , IsNull(EndDate, '2999-01-01') as EndDate
from c2
where JobTitle <> NextJobTitle or NextJobTitle is null
)
select *
from c3
where StartDate <= EndDate
```

**Result:**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ JobTitle      ║ StartDate  ║ EndDate    ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 2          ║ BSA III       ║ 2016-10-01 ║ 2999-01-01 ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 10         ║ Sales Agent   ║ 2016-10-01 ║ 2016-10-14 ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 10         ║ Sales Agent 2 ║ 2016-10-15 ║ 2016-10-15 ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 10         ║ Sales Agent 3 ║ 2016-10-16 ║ 2999-01-01 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Hi Flicker, thanks for your answer, but my sample data is correct. Inserts added later (higher ID numbers) should be able to overwrite changes if their effective date comes sooner.

Comment: Nice use of lead and lag, I only have 2008 so I did a cursor :(

Comment: bigger ID with smaller EffectiveDate? That's kind of unusual. I see you have changed your sample data. I try to adjust my answer.

Comment: @ScholarYoshi, I adjusted my answer with your recent sample data

Comment: @HolmesIV, Thank you. implementing LEAD and LAG in previous SQL is cumbersome but doable. Cursor is not too bad if dataset is small. :)